# Equivalence relation and the quotient set

Tags: abstract-algebra

Good day everyone,

let $\sim$ be an equivalence relation on some set $E$, by definition we have $\bar{x}=\{y \in E \mid x \sim y\}$ the equivalence class of x, and $E/\sim$ the quotient set (set of all equivalence classes).

Wouldn't $E/\sim$ contain redundancies since if $x \sim y$ with $x,y \in E$ then $\bar{x}=\bar{y}$? Which is a problem because sets are composed of different elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\sim$ is an *equivalence relation*, then we know it is a reflexive, symmetric, and transitive relation. Only then can say that $\sim$ partitions $E$ into equivalence classes. Let $x \sim y$. Then for any $z\in \bar x$, we know that $x\sim z$ and $y \sim x$ (by the symmetry), and then $y\sim z$ (transitivity). Therefore, if $x \sim y$ then $\bar x = \bar y$.

Comment: Yes and therefore $\bar{x}$ and $\bar{y}$ intersect hence only one should be considered in $E/\sim$

Comment: Am I failing to notice something?

Comment: Not only do they intersect, we showed that they must be the exact same set. In $E/\sim$ this corresponds to *one* equivalence class that is equal to $\bar x$ and to $\bar y$

Comment: Alright I did a blunder here, thank you.
I was thinking that since $x$ and $y$ are different elements of their own then each one should see its equivalent class in $E/\sim$.

Comment: Not just that, how to explain ..

Comment: Are you asking for more explanation? And if so, on what?

Comment: No no, I'm good thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No, it doesn't. Given two sets $A,B$. Define $A=B$ iff $\forall x [x\in A\Leftrightarrow x\in B]$. Thus a set can be represented such that it contains an element multiple times and the ordering of elements in the set doesn't matter, e.g., $\{1,2,3\}=\{3,2,1\} = \{1,2,1,3,1\}$.

Answer (score 0):

Equivalence classes are defined over equivalence relations so them are well defined.
Check [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation)